# convert a json to string in js and back to json on server with firebase

Tags: java, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

javascript code: (It creates a json object -> convert to json string -> upload to firebase)

```
var data = {}
data.systemId = "21341"

// convert json to string
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

// push to firebase

var update = {}
update[1718964] = dataString
firebase.database().ref("/data").update(update)
```

Now the data in firebase console looks like:

[image]

Now i try to read the data in Java using `Apache httpClient`

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);         
response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String dataString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

System.out.println(dataString); 
// ABOVE sysout exactly prints below with quotes included
// "{\"systemId\":\"21341\"}"
```

I was expecting it to print. 
`{"systemId" : "21341"}`

**So why it is printing data with `\` and starting ending quotes?**

WHy i expect it to print it without quotes and slash is based on below code

```
String temp = "{\"systemId\" : \"21341\"}"
System.out.println(temp);
// prints
//{"systemId" : "21341"}
```

**What mistake am i making ?**
PS:
The content type of the get request is "application/json" but content received is just a string... the problem i think is in how i am handling the data in java.. **but still dont know how to fix it**?

[image]

Comment: `dataString` is a string. You need to parse it as an object first.

Comment: Because you are reading the data as plain text instead of treating it as a JSON string. Parse that text with the `javax.json` package or another JSON library like Jackson or GSON.

Comment: @Cerbrus `dataString` is a string.. true.. which is intended... why did the temp printed it without quotes and  slash

Comment: @user2410148: The `println` doesn't render the outer "quotes" of the string, so there's no need to escape the inner quotes of the string.

Comment: added a better version of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098101/fetching-json-from-firebase-as-string-not-working-in-java